# Can I use the result of a SUM function in the WHERE clause of MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

For example suppose I have

```
SELECT sum(...) as total
```

Can I do something like

```
WHERE total > 10
```

When I try that actual syntax I get an error

> invalid column name 'total'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are using `sum` with `group by`

```
select sum(...) 
group by Col1 
having sum(...) > 10
```

without `group by`

```
select sum(...) 
having sum(...) > 10
```

if you want to use a column name you need to place the query in subquery

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT sum(...) as total 
) as T
WHERE total > 10
```

Answer (score 2):

> "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference".

HAVING is like WHERE with aggregate functions, or you could use a subquery.

```
select name, sum(amount) as total
from table
group by name
having sum(amount) > 10
```

Or

```
select * from(
   select name, sum(amount) as total 
) as temp
where temp.total > 10
```

Comment: @daniel i hope this is helpful for you